# Displaying translated taxonomy terms

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I am trying to achieve a multilingual site that shares its content across all the (currently two) languages, so the same content resides under the same term no matter what language is currently active.

I've been told that I should use the i18n module, which I did. So right now I have all the names of the terms translated in both languages, so that is all working as it should.

The problem is that when I change the language to, for example, Arabic, all the term titles are still in English, even though I have a nice list of translated Arabic counterparts.

So the question I would like to ask is: is there a way to get Drupal to replace all the English terms with the Arabic ones wherever a term's name is displayed? (so make it behave as if every term name has been run through Drupal's t() function)

Most people who tried to answer this question just suggested I use the i18n module. So yeah, I already did that. **I have the translations for the term names, but when changing the language, the term names are still in English**

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**Edit**: Please note that I am not talking about a specific module here. For example, when I go to the admin panel's "Add Node" page, I have a drop-down box filled with terms that I have translated, with the language set to Arabic, and yet they still show up as English. This goes to show that it does not work with Drupal Core modules, so it is not likely to be caused by a poorly coded module per se.

Comment: I would expect this to "just work". You probably have a simple configuration error, or possibly a badly coded module/template. You need to "divide and conquer" the problem, as we can't do the debugging for you.

Comment: So would I. But it doesn't seem to work, and I just wanted to find out whether this was the default behaviour, i.e. whether more steps are needed to actually get the translations to show. I'm not asking anyone to solve the problem as a whole, but just to shed some light on the whole process of getting the term names to show up as translated (a task that shouldn't be hard to begin with). I don't think it's a module's fault, as the default Drupal dropdown boxes don't translate it either.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed, the problem was that the translations did not have the correct context linked to the translation.

Comment: Is there any chance you could summarise your solution  and mark your own answer accepted?